# javascript eval on php json_encode output - security concerns

Tags: javascript, php

Here is a quick example of something I was wondering about, before we start I am aware that eval should only be used when absolutely needed.

Let's say I have an endpoint that runs some code like this:

**endpoint.php**

```
<?php
    $input = sanitised($_POST['someData']);
    $array = someDatabaseQueryMethod($input);
    echo 'runtime.getItem("'.A_SAFE_DEFINED_CONSTANT.'").stateChange({"newValues":'.json_encode($array).'});';
?>
```

then I have an **index.php** that looks like this:

```
... ommitted...
<body>

$.ajax({
    url : "./endpoint.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : {someData: 1},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        eval(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        //error logic here
    }
});

...
```

Is there a situation that can occur where some content in $array (which, lets say, could contain anything at all, multi dimensional, loads of different strings / other data types, but will always be a valid array that won't cause json_encode to fail) could mean that the eval statement could be vulnerable to some kind of injection?

Effectively I always want .stateChange to recieve an object that it can take a look at and decide what to do in this example

I know this might seem like quite a convoluted example, it is taken out of context - this is the smallest verifiable example i could come up with.

**EDIT**: while the above is closes to what I am doing, i guess the smallest example would actually be this:

**endpoint.php**

```
<?php
    $input = sanitised($_POST['someData']);
    $array = someDatabaseQueryMethod($input);
    echo 'var a = '.json_encode($array).';';
?>
```

**OK guys i get it - no need for more comments that do not answer the question which is not about different methods of doing the same thing but thanks for your feedback**

**It would be great to get an example of where this would break, not hearsay about how bad eval is.**

Comment: Wow this is hard to read, If you could write the question in one sentence what is your question?

Comment: Why `eval` the data? Just tell jQuery you're expecting a JSON response and it'll parse it as JSON.

Comment: indeed. why have your code return a function call in the first place? that'd be more JSONP. why not just return the json-encoded array and let JSON.parse() handle that automatically? there'd be no "execution" concerns, because json.parse doesn't use eval, and you wouldn't be sending executable code in the first place.

Comment: added a TLDR for you @DustinPoissant, andy - as stated in the question, this is part of a much larger example and i know it does not make sense on its own without pasting thousands of lines of code.

Comment: In my opinion, in such a context, the eval is just unneeded. I would personally use eval only if I literally have no other alternative, like in a situation where I have to execute some javascript code which is stored on the server and generated according to some user settings but not being influenced by any mean from any user's data. There was a nice topic about eval in stackoverflow about when to use it with ajax requests, but I can't find that answer anymore.

Comment: Even just for the sake of decoupling... if you return code which must be compatible and run correctly in the client, you're unnecessarily tying implementation details of both the server and client together, and will have a much harder time evolving either in the future. You should always only exchange "neutral" data and let the respective sides worry about *code execution* themselves.

Comment: @briosheje I have a hard time coming up with good reasons to use eval, especially from the server; even making an impromptu interpreted scripting language, or JSON command structure, works fine for most cases. The few exceptions I know of are: Checking for ES6 syntax support, and letting a developer actually write JavaScript code into an input element on the page to check whether it works with some API. (Much like the codesample editors we get in Stack Overflow)

Comment: @Katana314: Indeed, I perfectly agree with you. I don't remember where (here, in stackoverflow) I saw a very complete and explanatory answer showing some examples where, in fact, it was "okay" to use eval. That said, I think the last time I've used eval was about.. 4 years ago? because I didn't yet know that it was evil, I was young. For instance, the best I can guess, is that in this specific case (the one about that question) there is literally no reason to use eval.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a situation that can occur where some content in $array
>   (which, lets say, could contain anything at all, multi dimensional,
>   loads of different strings / other data types, but will always be a
>   valid array that won't cause json_encode to fail) could mean that the
>   eval statement could be vulnerable to some kind of injection?

Yes, absolutely! If I were a hacker, I could very likely find a way to hijack a user's entire session if there's ever even the slightest mistake made in escaping user strings. There is absolutely no reason you should need to take that kind of risk. Use `JSON.parse(str)` instead. Since you're currently returning JavaScript code, change it to simply return your value as an object with two values that you automatically do two things with. (eg: `{stateChangeTarget: 'CONSTANT_IDENTIFIER', stateChangeData: {"newValues": [...]} }`) This will give you the array that you want. Then perform the expected functions in the result like this:

```
dataType: "json"
success: function(data)
{
     runtime.getItem(data.stateChangeTarget).stateChange(data.stateChangeData);
},
```

This is also extensible to other client applications. If you decide to write a mobile app, that app won't be able to run JavaScript, and so it'll be lost when the server returns a pure JavaScript command with no neutral way to access the data (JSON)

Comment: Thanks, i understand the options already. I just find it strange that everyone dooms eval, yet returning echo json_encode($arr) instead in index seems (based on https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/) would result in the same code executing (i.e. eval of my json_encode output) in older versions of jquery, thanks anyway.